# Healthcare Benefits Change by employer after 2 week notice

Tags: job-change

My husband put his 2 week notice in on 2/29/16 and then received a note with his check stating that because his last day is 3/16/16, the company would only pay one quarter of the health insurance premium for the month when the employee handbook clearly states that the company pays half the the premium. We are looking for some guidance because that, to me, does not seem legal to do. Any thoughts or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid that we are not legal experts on Workplace SE. Your best course of action would be to contact a lawyer familiar with the laws in your area.

Comment: Kristina, does the employee handbook say "half the premium for the month" or "half of the premium for the portion of the month worked"?

Answer (score 6):

First, the bad news: You are not likely to prevail on this, regardless of the legality.  It costs a LOT of money and takes a LOT of time to fight a legal battle.

Having said that:

Step One is for your husband to talk with his HR rep, with a copy of the employee handbook in his hand, with the relevant language highlighted.

Assuming Step One is unsuccessful, Step Two would be to talk with an attorney.  The attorney will probably tell you that the deck is stacked against you, the odds of winning are very small, and the cost of the fight will far exceed the amount of money at issue.

You MIGHT get some traction with your state's Employment Commission, but this is unlikely.

Comment: I appreciate your comments. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 6):

But looking at the math the company is paying half

Health insurance is by the month.  You are only working 1/2 the month and they pay 1/2 of that.  1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4.  For the last 1/2 of the month you are not working and pay 100%.  I get a lot of companies would pay the half the whole month but your company is taking a defensible position.

If the wording is half the premium then you may have a case.  If the insurance is not available for 1/2 month then you could argue that is the companies problem.  But still I doubt you would win.

Comment: The question isn't clear, because we don't have the handbook, but that wouldn't be my understanding of what the OP meant.

Answer (score 2):

Always assume that when it comes to health care and insurance that everything will stop the moment you walk out the door. I have seen companies extend it to the end of the pay period, or the end of the month but there is no standard unless your state or national  labor law addresses it.

The company may also handle a reduction in force vs. quitting vs. getting fired differently. Sometimes it depends on the contract between the employer and the insurance company. It may even depend on if they are self-insuring or not.

Always ask and get clarification as early a possible. I have seen employees in the United States not spend flexible spending accounts when they didn't realize that there was a deadline.